# Move water without touching it

Tags: electromagnetism

If i had a cup of water, with flakes of black pepper in it - how could i move those flakes without physically touching them, or the water.

Also, temperature can't be used to influence it. The goal is to influence/move the water enough that it influences the pepper flakes.

If enough static electricity built up next to it, would that attract the water and move the specks? Would a magnet be able to move them (if so, how strong would that magnet have to be?)

Is there something else that would cause a molecule like h2o to move without touching it?